# Is it possible for data to be persisted when redeploying a parition table to a previously used disk?

Tags: filesystems, android, partition-table

I am currently working on a project which uses a custom Android operating system, the project requires going back and forth between different versions of this OS (android 5 and android 9 respectively). We sometimes notice that data from previous Android 9 uses, seems to persist after flashing back to Android 5, and then back to Android 9 again.

I have a feeling there's sectors of the storage that are used by Android 9, but not Android 5, and when the partition table is redeployed, those areas are still populated with files from the previous installation of Android 9.

We need to investigate exactly what happens in our "flashing" process but I'm curious to know, and this the crux oy my question, is this even theoretically possible?

Regarding the specifics how the OS flashes happen, from Android 9 to Android 5 they use the NXPMicro MFGTool2 v 1.0.0.1 (https://community.nxp.com/pwmxy87654/attachments/pwmxy87654/imx-processors/91189/1/Manufacturing%20Tool%20V2%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.pdf)

Android 9 is deployed to the device by a script in the recovery system that extracts the images and deploys them either by:

```
dd if={ImageFile} of= /dev/block/{mmcblk}
```

or

```
simg2img {ImageFile} {mmcblck}
```

A zip of data that is persisted between the upgraded is stored in the vendor mount at this point also. This is then extracted when Android 9 boots and restores the data from the before the update.

The process works from A5 to A9 and back again however the second, third etc... updates to A9 seem to indicate data from previous A( installations is hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, it is possible.

It depends on how exactly you switching versions, but in very broad and generalized explanation: the OS itself is located one one folder, and when you switch, you just overwrite that one folder. But once the OS is started, it can create another folders and create some data in them. And subsequent re-installations do not touch those secondary folders...

It is not possible to give a more specific answer without knowing how exactly you do the "flashing".

On a side note: why do you switch OSes on the same storage in the first place? It would be much cheaper and more reliable to just take two independent devices. What is you real-life task which requires regular swapping of OS???

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have possibly made the original question more confusing by (trying to) describe the process for getting both A5 and A9 on the device. The use case here, to answer your question is an OS upgrade of an Android device